# How to get disappeared keyboard back?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, keyboard

I am using `Android 5` and, on rare occasions, my keyboard disappears or becomes unavailable when I enter editable fields in different apps (browser, FB, etc).  Once that happens, what can I do, other than rebooting, to get the keyboard to reappear once I am in editable fields?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this on rare occasion. Often simply backing out of the app, and optionally removing it from the list of recently-used apps (which quits an app a bit more calmly than an End/End All), will restore functionality once the app is relaunched.

Sometimes a web page or web-based app, like Facebook, will refresh itself in the background, and that can disconnect the keyboard from the field being edited. Sometimes it's a slowdown elsewhere in the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Usually changing focus away from the text element then refocusing by tapping on it should work but if it doesnt then you can open the app again by removing it from recents and relaunching it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the keyboard disappearance problem and temporarily fixed it by going into Settings -> Apps -> (All Apps) -> Google Keyboard and clicking on "Uninstall Updates". But it keeps automatically updating the keyboard and the problem comes back. So I did not get at the root of the problem.